# finding undefined or null value from object inside object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, reactjs, object

i would like to push keys inside array if found undefined or null

```
const obj = {
  name:'ab',
  edu:'av',
  degres:{
    a1:'',
    b1:'1'
  },
  platform:undefined
 }
```

i want an output like

```
  `['a1','platform']`
```

as the value for a1 and platform were null and undefined

i have treid this solution but it doesnt work

```
 function iterater(obj){
  let blankValues = [];
  Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && (typeof obj[key] === "object")) {
        iterater(obj[key])
      } else {
          if (typeof obj[key] === "undefined" || obj[key] === ''){
            blankValues.push(key);
         }
      }
    })
  return blankValues;

}
```

but this somehow only return ['platform'] only,but the expected output should be ['platform','a1'],i think when running iterater(obj[key]),the value of array (blankValues) gets blank as it doesnt perserve it,but please help me with appropriate logic and structure

Comment: You're using `.map()` as though it was `.forEach()`, so it's creating a new array, filling it with `undefined` and then throwing it away. Also, you don't need the `.hasOwnProperty` test, since `Object.keys()` will only give you "own" properties.

Comment: ...and an empty string is distinct from `null` in JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because you're re-defining `blankValues` as an empty array in every iteration of the recursive loop. To fix this you could accept the array as an optional argument of the function so that values get pushed to it on each iteration.

Also note that, as @[ziggy wiggy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10671583/ziggy-wiggy) pointed out in the comments, your logic will fail when a `null` value is encountered as `typeof obj[key] === "object"` would be `true`. You need a specific null check too.

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'ab',
  edu: 'av',
  degres: {
    a1: '',
    b1: '1'
  },
  platform: undefined,
  foo: null
}

function iterater(obj, arr) {
  arr = arr || [];
  Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && (typeof obj[key] === "object") && obj[key] !== null) {
      iterater(obj[key], arr)
    } else {
      if (typeof obj[key] === "undefined" || obj[key] === null || obj[key].trim() === '') {
        arr.push(key);
      }
    }
  })
  return arr;
}

console.log(iterater(obj));
```

Note that I also added a `trim()` call to test the empty string. Your previous logic would accept whitespace-filled strings as valid values.

Comment: oh yes true got you,Thanks,and there any easy or short cut solution with power of es6

Comment: No problem, glad to help. You could potentially shorten the code by recursively using `reduce()` on the keys of each object (I've not tested it), but that code would be very difficult to follow. In terms of readability/shortness this is ideal, IMO.

Comment: Recursively using `reduce()` or even `map()` or `forEach()` would do the job yes, but as Rory greatly said, this solution is the best in term of readability.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will fail if there's ever a `null` value, since `typeof obj[key] === "object"` will be `true`, so `Object.keys(null)` will error.

Comment: @ziggywiggy thank you. I updated the answer with regards to that

Answer (score 0):

As you said yourself, when you call `iterater(obj[key])` it sets a new local `blankValues` and puts values in it. So i think you should put `blankValues` outside the function. 
And then you don't have to return it (or you can if you want it as a return value).

Or you can pass `blankValues` as a parameter of `iterater` in both the main call and the "inside" call

Answer (score 0):

You need to consume the result of recursive call. For example add it back to `blankValues` like this `blankValues.push(...iterater(obj[key]))`

```js
const obj = {
  name:'ab',
  edu:'av',
  degres:{
    a1:'',
    b1:'1'
  },
  platform:undefined
 }

 function iterater(obj){
  let blankValues = [];
  Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && (typeof obj[key] === "object")) {
        blankValues.push(...iterater(obj[key]))
      } else {
          if (typeof obj[key] === "undefined" || obj[key] === ''){
            blankValues.push(key);
         }
      }
    })
  return blankValues;

}

console.log(iterater(obj))
```

Answer (score 0):

You must push the result returned by the recursive call to your array.
Change:

```
iterater(obj[key])
```

for:

```
blankValues.push(...iterater(obj[key]))
```

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'ab',
  edu: 'av',
  degres: {
    a1: '',
    b1: '1'
  },
  platform: undefined
}

 function iterater(obj){
  let blankValues = [];
  Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && (typeof obj[key] === "object")) {
        blankValues.push(...iterater(obj[key]))
      } else {
          if (typeof obj[key] === "undefined" || obj[key] === ''){
            blankValues.push(key);
         }
      }
    })
  return blankValues;

}

console.log(iterater(obj));
```

Here is another way to do it using `Object.entries()`, `Object.keys()`, `Array.reduce()`, `Array.flat()` and `Array.isArray()`. This implementation works for arrays too.

```js
const obj = {
  name:'ab',
  edu:'av',
  something: [{ a: 1 }, { a: '' }],
  degres:{
    a1:'',
    b1:'1'
  },
  platform:undefined
};

function getEmptyProps(obj) {
  if (!Object.keys(obj).length) { return []; }
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
    if (val === undefined || val === null || val.toString().trim() === '') {
      acc.push(key);
    } else if (Array.isArray(val)) {
      acc.push(val.map(getEmptyProps).flat());
    } else if (typeof val === 'object') {
      acc.push(getEmptyProps(val));
    }
    return acc.flat();
  }, []);
}

console.log(getEmptyProps(obj))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a check for falsy keys and return the key, if the property is an object, the check the object.

```js
const
    getFalsy = o => Object.keys(o).reduce((r, k) => {
        if (!o[k]) return [...r, k];
        if (typeof o[k] === 'object') return [...r, ...getFalsy(o[k])];
        return r;
    }, []),
    object = { name: 'ab', edu: 'av', degres: { a1: '', b1: '1' }, platform: undefined };

console.log(getFalsy(object));
```